# Gcloud functions deployment doesn't find Golang template files

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, go-templates

I have written some Golang code which works when tested on my local machine. When I deploy this as a Google Cloud function it fails because it cannot open a template file. The line of code failing is:

```
    t, err := template.New("list.gohtml").ParseFiles("list.gohtml")
```

After this call `err` is set to `open list.gohtml: no such file or directory`

The file is in the same directory as the go source file and is not listed in `.gcloudignore` or `.gitignore`. The gcloud functions documentation says all files in the directory will be uploaded unless listed in one of those ignore files and if I run `gcloud meta list-files-for-upload` then the file `list.gohtml` *is* included in the list displayed.

Is there some magic folder layout to make this work, or an option to the `gcloud functions deploy` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on @DazWilkin's reply, I now call the function below at the start of the serving function.

Rather than hardwiring the path into the template file names (which would make it fail when tested locally) this simply checks for the presence of the [Gcloud source file directory](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system) below the current one, and if present, makes it the working directory, so file resolution will now happen exactly as it does when tested locally.

```golang
import "os"

const gcloudFuncSourceDir = "serverless_function_source_code"

func fixDir() {
    fileInfo, err := os.Stat(gcloudFuncSourceDir)
    if err == nil && fileInfo.IsDir() {
        _ = os.Chdir(gcloudFuncSourceDir)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! If found your comment on my answer here and it was very useful using Go 1.19 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63385920/no-such-file-or-directory-on-google-cloud-function-using-go-1-13

Answer (score 1):

If there's no `go.mod` file (in other words, if modules aren't enabled), then the behavior changes and the files are under `src/<package-name>/`, not under `serverless_function_source_code/`. The `main.go` file used to drive the cloud function resides in `src/serverless_function_app/main/main.go`.

For example:

I have a Go application with the following two files:

```
listfiles/file_system.go
listfiles/tmpl/letter.html
```

I deployed it with these commands:

```
cd listfiles
gcloud functions deploy ListFiles --runtime go113 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated
```

The result was that the current directory was set to `/srv`. Underneath `/srv` was a typical GOROOT tree with `src/` and `pkg/` directories. For example:

```
.googlebuild
.googlebuild/source-code.tar.gz
pkg
pkg/linux_amd64
pkg/linux_amd64/github.com
pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform
pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go
pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go/funcframework.a
src
src/cloud.google.com
src/cloud.google.com/go
src/cloud.google.com/go/.git
src/cloud.google.com/go/.git/HEAD
src/cloud.google.com/go/.git/branches
[... snip...]
src/go.uber.org/zap/zaptest/testingt_test.go
src/go.uber.org/zap/zaptest/timeout.go
src/go.uber.org/zap/zaptest/timeout_test.go
src/go.uber.org/zap/zaptest/writer.go
src/go.uber.org/zap/zaptest/writer_test.go
src/listfiles
src/listfiles/file_system.go
src/listfiles/tmpl
src/listfiles/tmpl/letter.html
src/serverless_function_app
src/serverless_function_app/main
src/serverless_function_app/main/main.go
```